# Downloading a PNG Binary with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My server is receiving a PNG binary from a third party server which looks like this:

```
�PNG


IHDR���2%FiCCPICC Profile(�c``I,(�aa``��+)
rwR���R`��� ���`����\\��T��Q��k� ��.ȬE2��\���o��ט�QWJjq2���i�E%�)@�ryI��d�d���!�
 v�}�&$�Ⱦd$g$�`|d�$!��#�������BhNIQ����JR+J@�s~AeQfzF��#0�R<��t��@aQ��8,�8b�@V�@��X�Ö�d���$An��Q�E�p0~c)N36����30�N���s8�&�����������e̷|cn`&���eXIfMM*>F(�iN����x���ASCIIScreenshot7�   pHYs%%IR$��iTXtXML:com.adobe.xmp<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 6.0.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:exif="http://ns.adobe.com/exif/1.0/">
         <exif:PixelYDimension>1924</exif:PixelYDimension>
         <exif:PixelXDimension>3808</exif:PixelXDimension>
         <exif:UserComment>Screenshot</exif:UserComment>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
_���iDOT�(��N�ɦ�@IDATx���U��� DQY"Xc��
```

I was sending the response straight to the client by doing this:

```
const file = await downloadImageFromThirdParty()
res.status(200).send(file)
```

When I tested this with postman I was able to see the raw data, but if I make the request with the postman to the third party server I'm able to see the image as a response.

After this, I did some manipulation on my request and response header but still, it doesn't display the image on the postman.

```
let file = await downloadImageFromThirdParty()
file = Buffer.from(file)
res.set('Content-Type', "image/png;base64");
res.set('Content-Disposition', "attachment;filename*=UTF-8''Step-2.png")
return res.status(200).end(attachment, 'binary');
```

What I'm missing?

Please forgive any typo since English is my second language.

Comment: Setting the response type to blob is correct. If downloadAttachment returns a blob, just pass that to FileSaver.saveAs as the first argument.

Comment: @musa yes, you are right. I found that my problem is with how my server returns the image since postman is not able to display the image either. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: What data type does downloadImageFromThirdParty return?

Comment: @Musa it returns a string that contains those weird characters at the beginning of my question.

Comment: Then you'll have to fix that function